# InDesign: how to change the underline opacity?

Tags: adobe-indesign, transparency

I added a 15pt weight -4 pt offset underline to this paragraph and I was wondering if it's possible to lower the opacity of the underline without changing the text opacity.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The Underline options won't allow you to change the opacity of the underline, but you can change the color and tint of it. So you can make it 50% black, but that won't make it 50% transparent. Except for white which does not allow tints.

[image]

The only way to achieve what you're after is to remove the underline and manually draw these as white boxes underneath the text, which you can then set to a lower opacity.

Comment: Or, perhaps easier: duplicate the text box so you have two right on top of each other, change the blend mode/opacity of the bottom one to fit your needs, remove the underline from the top copy, and then group the two. Easier to update than manually created boxes.

Comment: Not behind my desktop – does setting the underline color swatch to "Overprint" do anything useful? (Best checked – just to be complete – in "Overprint Preview".)